# Docker Rootless and compose volume with incorrect permissions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions

I followed [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) to make Docker run in rootless mode. It works fine, unless when it comes to create volumes where both the container and the host can access. Even adding a user and group to *docker-compose.yml*, it doesn't work:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  wp:
    user: "1000:1000"
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - ${IP}:8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wp:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  
  db:
    image: mysql:latest # https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ - or mariadb https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
    ports:
      - ${IP}:3068:3306
    command: [
        '--default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password',
        '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
        '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
    ]
    volumes:
      - ./wp-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
```

If the `wp` folder is created by the host before running the container, I get "Permission Denied" issues when the container tries to create the application files.

Without the `user:"1000:1000"` part, the `wp` folder has its files created, but I can only access them from the host when using sudo.

I would like to have access to the volume files using the rootless Docker without needing to use sudo, or manually changing the permissions, would it be possible?

```bash
grep ^$(whoami): /etc/subuid
testuser:100000:65536
```

```bash
grep ^$(whoami): /etc/subgid
testuser:100000:65536
```